# Jupyter notebook presentation / RISE

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda

I want to make presentations via Jupyter NB . I install RISE through Conda prompt :

```
conda install -c damianavila82 rise
```

It runs properly , but the presentation icon does'nt appear in Jupyter NB.
Please help .

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `jupyter-nbextension install rise --py --sys-prefix`?

Also note that is no longer a supported installation strategy. Use the following as described [here](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/maint-5.6/installation.html):

```
conda install -c conda-forge rise
```

Comment: I run that before, but it didn't solve the issue . The icon didn't appeared.

Comment: Then I would uninstall what you have and go to the documentation, and use one of the current documented ways to install. It seems like the `pip` route specifically talks about it handling enabling, and so I'd advocate for that.

Comment: Is there any other way to make presentation via Jupyter NB ?
It would be highly appreciated if you advise how delete codes from presentation.

Comment: There are other ways. You could make pdfs or what you need. And nbviewer has a way to present as slides if you notebook has slideshow metadata, see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jupyter/IO9LGZchURw). However, RISE is the best. If you want to hide the code, I am working on [a MyBinder-launchable version of jupyter-rise with the hide_code extension](https://github.com/fomightez/jupyter-rise_with-hide_code) enabled; however, it isn't done yet as I didn't finish porting it over from just getting it working with [Binder & Jupyter](https://github.com/fomightez/jupyter_hide_code).

Comment: By the way, if you were still having installation problems, you can go to https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-rise and click the `launch binder` button to run Jupyter-rise in your browser using a remote machine. You can use that repo as a template to make your own repo and then add your content to it and adjust the launch button URL to use your repo, if you are okay with your content being public in Github. Note that it will still work if you aren't comfortable with leaving your content on Github because you can launch a session and then upload your notebook to the running session.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

Here is what I did to resolve the issue:

1. First I install the pip library of rise

```bash
pip install RISE
```

2. Then, I run the conda command

```bash
conda install -c conda-forge rise
```

3. Now, Activate your conda

```bash
conda activate
```

4. Now, run the below command.

```bash
jupyter nbextension install rise --py --user
```

5. last, enable nbextension to use rise

```bash
jupyter nbextension enable rise --py --user
```

For more detail, you can also refer to the following GitHub issue page:
https://github.com/damianavila/RISE/issues/520